# angularJS TypeError is not a function when called using on-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

The error I receive is the following

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Scope.$scope.AddCardToList
```

the code in html

```
 <button type="button" ng-if="$index == 0" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="AddCardToList(card)">{{edition.multiverse_id}}</button>
```

javascript code of the function AddCardToList

```
$scope.AddCardToList = function (card) {
        if (!$scope.decklist) { $scope.decklist = {}; }
        $log.info("Adding " + card.name + " to your decklist.");
        $scope.decklist.push(card);
    };
```

I'm not seeing while I get an undefined whenever I try to push card in the $scope.decklist array
but the function and call to the function works just fine when I don't try to push the object in the array.

Is there a preferred method on creating and pushing/popping objects in an array in angular that I'm not seeing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean `$scope.decklist = [];` instead of `{}` Push is a function on the array not on an object literal. Or just do `$scope.decklist = $scope.decklist || []`

Comment: yes i'm an idiot!

I read on SO that to call an empty array would be $scope.decklist = {}; 

It works, thank you good sir!